# Add-Migration works in Package Manager Console but not in CLI

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, command-line-interface

When I run Add-Migration from Package Manager Console everything is alright. But I get an error when run it in .NET Core command-line interface.

I also got error in `dotnet ef database update`

Am I missing something or making a mistake?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your DbContext file in the Infrastructure Class library? If not, you can use the following command :

dotnet ef migrations add RemoveSeedData --project **THE PROEJECT PATH CONTAINING DBCONTEXT**
Example : 
dotnet ef migrations add RemoveSeedData --project ../MyProject.Data

Comment: DbContext is in Infrastructure Class Library.
Running blew command also resulted in same error:
dotnet ef migrations add initial --project infrastructure

Comment: can you flag your startup project with '-s' . You should run a command like : dotnet ef migrations add initial -s ../MainWebProject/